# Websocket from Kafka messages

Tags: django, apache-kafka, websocket

I am working on an IoT project that uses MQTT protocol to transport the sensor data from embedded devices to an App. For this i have created,

1. A MQTT broker to send the data from the device.
2. A custom bridge that push data from MQTT broker to my Kafka broker
3. Django server to push the messages via websocket to the App

Right now, What i need is to consume the Kafka messages from django, save to the DB and then push this data to client via websockets. But i don't have much idea regarding how to consume Kafka messages from Django.
So far the solution in my mind is using [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/), start a kafka consumer, push the data to DB and then to websockets.

Is this a good approach? If not, what would be a good solution to solve this?

Comment: Can you have some delay on push data on database?

Comment: Yes, I can delay the data being written to the DB.

Comment: What specific issues are you having with defining a Kafka consumer and forwarding its data into the websocket sender? Alternatively, what's wrong with a standard API route that polls the database?

Comment: When i define a Kafka consumer that to write to DB in  `__init__.py`, i get the following error "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.". So this should only run after starting the app.
And regarding the polling, what i need is live data through websockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can add periodic task to consume a topic and bulk insert (or update) to database (it impact on the performance).

Comment: I can achieve this by using celery, but what if i want to stream live data into client device? I need to consume Kafka message and then push to websockets as soon as possible.

Comment: In all of my project, I use django command and push my data (There is just one point, number of consumer cannot be more the number of topic portions )